# Angularjs getting the button value

Tags: angularjs

I need to get the button `id` value using angularjs.I have written the code but i am getting the value as `"undefined"`.So please suggest me the code which i need to use.

My code is:

```
 <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary ole" data-toggle="tooltip"  id="buttonvalue" name="rdoResult"  value="SUN" ng-click="addvalue()"  ng-model="testDate23"  data-placement="left" data-original-title="this is a left tooltip">
      SUN
</button>

<button type="button"  ng-value="2"  class="btn btn-primary ole two" data-toggle="tooltip"  ng-click="addvalue()" 
 ng-model="testDate23" value="MON"  id="buttonvalue" data-placement="top" data-original-title="this is a top tooltip">
      MON
</button>
```

Script code:

```
$scope.addvalue = function() {
    var datevaluee=$scope.testDate23;
}
```

Comment: whatever the value of `testDate23` will be before binding , it will be same in the method. What you want in `$scope.testDate23` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the $event in ng-click function like below..

```
   ng-click="addvalue($event)"
```

below will be the function implementation

```
    $scope.addvalue = function(element) {
      $scope.testDate23 = element.currentTarget.value; // this will return the value of the button
    console.log( $scope.testDate23)
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
    <button ng-click="addvalue(testDate23='SUN')">
     button
    </button>
```

or

```
   <button ng-click="addvalue(testDate23='MON')">
    btn2
   </button>
```

Find fiddle [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2prxddu3/1/)

Hope it will help.

Comment: you can use it with multiple buttons, with `ng-repeat` also.

Answer (score 0):

Button is an input for submitting data, not setting data.

Comment: yes but when i click on that button i need to get the value

Comment: The only way i familiar with is via directive, scope.value = attrs.value

Comment: it is not working is there any to get the button value in angular

Comment: if you want the "value" remove the ng-value and vice versa. here is a plunkr that works https://plnkr.co/edit/0ZJsHVXULAV9JOnLRCH6?p=preview

Comment: I have seen the code but while loading the page the values is coming not when click on button please see that code

Comment: of course! the value of a button is not change when you click on it, unless you do so intentionally. something like element.attr('value', scope.someInput)

Answer (score 0):

You need use directive.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/60ovmmeq/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.getValue = function() {
      $scope.value = $scope.testDate23;
    }
  });
  
myApp.directive('buttonValue', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
       buttonValue:"="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch(function(){return attr.ngValue},function(newVal){
           scope.buttonValue = newVal;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="btnValue">
  <button ng-value="{{btnValue}}" ng-click="getValue()" button-value="testDate23">
    MON
  </button>
  <br>
  <pre>testDate23= {{testDate23}}</pre>
  <pre>value= {{value}}</pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set hardcoded value then use `ng-init`

```
<button type="button"  ng-init="value=2"  class="btn btn-primary ole two" data-toggle="tooltip"  ng-click="addvalue()" 
ng-model="testDate23" value="MON"  id="buttonvalue" data-placement="top" data-original-title="this is a top tooltip">
  MON
</button>
```

You can use value aywhere in your same template.